# Laravel Validation: Validate two dates and times and validate them logicaly

Tags: php, laravel, date, validation, datetime

I am struggling to set up a proper validation which validates two date inputs and two time inputs. This is my html code so far:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">Start date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="start_date">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">Start time</label>
    <input type="time" class="form-control" name="start_time">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">End date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="end_date">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">End time</label>
    <input type="time" class="form-control" name="end_time">
</div>
```

As you can see, you can enter the start date and start time separated as well as the end date and end time. This can lead to many logical erros such as having an end date + end time bevore the start time + start date or just an end date before a start time.

I want to allow the following combinations (if there is no start_time set it should automatically be set to 00:00 and if there is no end_time set it should automatically be set to 23:59):

1. start_date
2. start_date & start_time
3. end_date
4. end_date & end_time
5. start_date & end_date
6. start_date & start_time & end_date
7. start_date & end_date
8. start_date & start_time & end_date & end_time

This is what I got so far for the rules of my validator:

```
'start_date' => ['required_if:start_time,date_format:H:i', 'date', 'nullable'],
'start_time' => ['date_format:H:i', 'nullable'],
'end_date' => ['required_if:end_time,date_format:H:i', 'date', 'nullable'],
'end_time' => ['date_format:H:i', 'nullable'],
```

However, it is not really working and I don't know how to complete it. Any hints and ideas on how to solve my problem?

After I have validated the input the start and end date (+time) should also be validated logicaly. The start date (+time) has to be before the end date (+time).

Comment: Why not use `<input type="datetime-local">`?

Comment: As you can see it needs to be possible to enter a date without a time!

Comment: Could it make more sense to allow JS to handle the concatenation? Before submitting, append time to date and simply validate timestamp format and before/after logic. I feel like you're overcomplicating this by allow separate entry of `date` and `time`. And storing `date` and `time` separately in database is going to be a headache... `date` and `time` can be parsed individually from a fully-qualified timestamp, but it's harder to work with them if they are separate like that.

Comment: I need and have to validate it on the server side for security reasons!

Comment: It still would... You'd send the fully qualified timestamps as `start` and `end` instead of `start_date`, `end_date`, `start_time` and `end_time`.

Answer (score 3):

As @Tim Lewis has mentioned, it's easier to merge date and time to one input (via JS), then you can use Laravel's before_or_equal validator:

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'start_date'    => 'required|date',
    'end_date'      => 'required|date|after_or_equal:start_date',
]);
```

However, if for some reason you want to keep date & time separate, you can split validation into two steps. First, check if the date in start_date is *before* (not equal) to the end date. If that passes = validation passed, no need to check time at all. If it fails, then check if dates are equal and if start_time is less than end_time. Something like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'start_date'    => 'required|date',
    'end_date'      => 'required|date|after:start_date',
]); 
if( $validator->fails() ) { // Dates are the same or wrong, check time
    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
       'start_date'    => 'required|date',
       'end_date'      => 'required|date|date_equals:start_date',
       'start_time'    => 'required|date',
       'end_time'    => 'required|date|after_or_equal:start_time',
    ]); 
    if( $validator->fails() ) { // Data is invalid
       abort(400);
    }
}
```

Note that you'd use `date` type on time as well as on date, because it internally calls PHP's `strtotime()` which works for time also.